# Pad daily(ish) dataframe into hourly

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe of gasoline prices in my area I'd like to input to a dataframe of electricity prices. Issue being that my gasoline data is daily-ish while electricity prices are hourly.

How can I duplicate my daily gas values so I can fit it with my electricity price dataframe? Is there a smarter way to do this, where I can reference the gas prices in the electricity dataframe?

My data:

```
            Price   
Date                    
2022-10-20  16.19
2022-10-19  16.49
2022-10-18  16.69
2022-10-15  16.99
```

I need to do hourly analysis of comparison between the two, so averaging the electricity price to daily won't work.

I tried using the below, but it failed.

```
df.set_index('DateTime').resample('H').pad()
(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39966456/pandas-generating-hourly-data-from-daily-data-from-csv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```py
# convert index to datetime (if required):
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.asfreq("H").interpolate()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                         Price
Date                          
2022-10-15 00:00:00  16.990000
2022-10-15 01:00:00  16.985833
2022-10-15 02:00:00  16.981667
2022-10-15 03:00:00  16.977500
2022-10-15 04:00:00  16.973333
2022-10-15 05:00:00  16.969167
2022-10-15 06:00:00  16.965000
2022-10-15 07:00:00  16.960833

...

2022-10-19 21:00:00  16.227500
2022-10-19 22:00:00  16.215000
2022-10-19 23:00:00  16.202500
2022-10-20 00:00:00  16.190000
```